# UnknownArchetype: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart)

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a simple Maven 3.0.3 project with the command:

```
mvn -X  archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId=com.hordine  -DartifactId=hordineCmdTwitter
```

And Maven fails me miserably with the message:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Using catalog /Users/hordine/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml
[DEBUG] Not found archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=hordineCmdTwitter:1.0 in cache
[DEBUG] Archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=hordineCmdTwitter:1.0 doesn't exist
org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadNotFoundException: Requested org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=hordineCmdTwitter:jar:1.0 download does not exist.
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.common.DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.exists(DefaultArchetypeArtifactManager.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=hordineCmdTwitter:jar:1.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.125s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 01 15:13:35 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/12M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=test:1.0) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=test:1.0)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=test:1.0)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.UnknownArchetype: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart?-DgroupId=com.hordine??-DartifactId=test:1.0)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.ui.generation.DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.configureArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerationConfigurator.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.execute(CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java:205)
    ... 21 more
```

Why can't Maven find this Archetype? I used to be able to create projects with this archetype.

This is how my settings.xml is configured:

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>people.apache.snapshots</id>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The funny thing is, if I execute only "mvn archetype:generate" and press enter, maven lists a huge amount of archetypes, and offers me maven-archetype-quickstart as default. And if I press enter I manage to create a maven project.

Comment: I tried it again today and it worked. No idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might have been some invisible funny characters that were being copied from my blog. I was copying the maven command from this post of mine: http://hordine.com/?p=1637 , by selecting it and typing control + C. Now that I've added a toolbar to that source code, when I copy the maven command using the copy button of the toolbar, I don't get this error anymore.

Comment: Link is broken.